# Drawing Rectangle in second tab, function not called (Objective C via Xcode on Mac)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, user-interface

Sorry for the ridiculously newbie question, but I'm building a two-tabbed app. In the second tab I'm drawing a rectangle over an image.

In SecondViewCOntroller.m I've written:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0));
NSLog(@"rectangle drawn!");
                  }
```

And of course it's not being called. I can't remember, do I need to create a paint function? How do I call drawRect when the second tab is opened?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you create a class(`YourView`) which is subclass of `UIView`. You implement code in your viewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   YourView *temp = [[YourView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];

    [self.view addSubview:temp];
}
```

You write your method(`- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`) in `YourView.m` file. Try like this. I think it will helpful to you.

Comment: When I add your code to the subclass I get "Incompatible pointer types sending 'ScanAnimation *' to parameter of type 'UIView *' ". What am I doing wring here?

Comment: Creating that subclass creates a .h .m and .xib file, where is the drawRect function relevant?

Comment: I think you created UIViewController not UIView. First right click on any file and select New File--->Objective-C Class then write class name in 'Class' and select UIView in 'Subclass of'.

Comment: Yes, fixed it. OK, so 2 files have been created, so I'm left with the original SecondViewController .m .h and .xib, and now I also have myDrawing .h and .m. Exactly where do I write what code?

Answer (score 2):

The `-drawRect:` method is on `UIView`, not `UIViewController`. You need to:

- create a subclass of `UIView`
- override `-drawRect:` in that class
- make sure that your SecondViewController loads a nib that contains a view of that class, or directly creates a view of that class